# Проблема с webhook telegram api

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Пишу свой бот. Хочу использовать webhook для получения новых сообщений. Установка webhook прошла успешно, а вот как получать новые сообщения? Какой код надо написать на сервере для приема этих новых сообщений?

Answer (score 0):

Инициализируем подключение:

```
$botToken = "_ТОКЕН_ОТ_@BotFather";
$website = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $botToken;
```

Получаем сообщение:

```
$content = file_get_contents("php://input"); //олучаем json-ответ
$update = json_decode($content, TRUE); //декодируем json
$message = $update["message"]; //получаем объект Message
```

Получаем данные из сообщения:

```
$chatId = $message["chat"]["id"]; //ID чата, где должен присутствовать бот
$text = $message["text"]; //текст сообщения
```